# Rails - Joinear tablas de un modelo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente consulta que no me funciona:

```
  def self.search(profesor) ->pasa como parametro el nombre del profesor
    Curso.joins(:user).where("LOWER(users.name) LIKE ?", "%#{profesor}%")
  end
```

Tengo un curso con un atributo user_id (corresponde al profesor que da ese curso)

Tengo la table user con un id y un name.

Necesitaria formular una consulta donde me traiga todos aquellos cursos donde el profesor = user.name desde el modelo de cursos. Alguna idea?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

No se como tengas tus modelos, pero creo que en este caso una relación "uno" a "muchos" es lo que necesitas.

Cambié el nombre de la clase de "Curso" a "Courses" en inglés, sólo porque rails pluraliza los nombres (Course -> Courses).

Solo algo para tomar en cuenta. El método está utilizando el nombre del profesor, tal como lo requieres, sin embargo, corres el riesgo de que existan dos profesores con el mismo nombre y por lo tanto, mostrar los cursos de ambos profesores.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

    def self.search(profesor)
      user = User.find_by(name: profesor) # encuentra al usuario
      Course.find_by(user_id: user.id) # encuentra los cursos de ese usuario
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end
```

Espero que esto te sirva.